# Last digits via PowerMod

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Do you have an idea why this produces different results?

```
PowerMod[2003, 2002^2001, 1000]
```

> `241`

```
PowerMod[2003, 2002 * 2001, 1000]
```

> `9`

The book I'm following presents a somewhat convoluted solution and it gets to "241" for the last three digits. Reducing the base and utilizing Euler's theorem results to "009" though.

Comment: "The book I'm following" - which book? In any event, [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_theorem) proceeds like this: `PowerMod[2003, PowerMod[2002, 2001, EulerPhi[1000]], 1000]`.

Comment: @J.M. Oh, it's some exercise book on number theory in my mother tongue. In fact, I'm having difficulties with some Project Euler problems and I'm brushing up on the subject.

Comment: Both results are correct. Why was there an expectation they might give the same result?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Arithmetic mistake I see now, 2003^(2002^2001), which is the problem, is not the same as (2003^2002)^2001 which is 2003^(2002*2001).